# Asp.net mvc and jquery mobile authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile application using MVC 4. And I'm securing it. The application has 2 pages ("home" and "Clientes")

When the application starts it asks me for a username and password, with this being its URL `http://localhost:59170/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f`.

I login and go to the home page. This is the url I can see on IE `http://localhost:59170/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f`.

From this page I go to the  Clientes page. This is the url that I can see on IE `http://localhost:59170/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f#/Clientes`. At the moment all works ok (Though url like something stranger).

The problem occurs when I press the back button on IE. It must go to the home page but I go to `http://localhost:59170/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f#/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f` where it asks me to login.

What might cause this behaviour and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you request a page that requires authentication, .NET will redirect you to your designated login page and append the requested URL to the URL.  That way, once the user has logged in successfully  it will redirect them to the page they requested automatically.  In your first URL for example the return URL encoded representation of / i.e. the root/ homepage of your site

It will keep redirecting you until you have authenticated.  If you don't want to have authentication on your homepage then just annotate your account controller with [Authorize] and not your home controller

Comment: But I authenticated ok first time, whhen go back return to login page but I´m authenticated. Problem only happends whith a mobile application.

Comment: I think the probelm It´s that login page are consedered as a normal page. If I ppress back in the login page I go to correct page. I must press twice back in order to go to page. thanks

Comment: Back by definition will always have the effect of just going backwards...it won't determine that you have since authenticated and perform a redirect since it isn't making a request to the server.  What you're describing is standard browser functionality

Comment: but, a MVC application not for mobile works ok. This only happens on mobile application

Comment: what do you class as a mobile application?  Are you using Jquery mobile?  If so this uses it's own mechanism for handling the back action which might be the reason for this behaviour.  Check out http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: yes, I´m using jquery mobile. There are any way to solve it? Thanks